# Do we need the tag "php"? If we need it, which other tags should we use?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need [php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php)? If we need it, which other tags should be have?

I guess that if we keep [php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php), then we should also have [javascript](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), and [html](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html).
Aren't there any better tags we should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the php tag would make sense in some cases, for instance "Why isn't Drupal completely OOP PHP?".

Similar language-based tags would be javascript, html (and html-5?), css (css-3?) and xml. I can also imagine other technology-based tags like xml-rpc, soap, rest, apache, iis, varnish, memcached, etc. However it will always need to be specific to Drupal, otherwise it's a question for Stack Overflow, Server Fault or another SE site.